# Retrieve values from one list to another list on button click "sharepoint online"

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom

I have a SharePoint list "A" which should create a button whenever we add a new item to the list,  and when we click on that button it should redirect to the list "B" `newform.aspx` with the list item values from the list "A".

list "B" will have couple of new columns other than coloumns in list "A". But it should only create the item in list"B" when user clicks on save button in list"B" `newform.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a lookup column in the "List B" to lookup from the "List A", then create column "Link"(single line of text) in "List A", and use JSLink to build the Link.

1.Save the following code as a js file(LinkField.js) and upload it into the SiteAssets Document Library.

```
(function () {   
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Link": { "View": LinkField }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function LinkField(ctx) {
    var currentId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
    var title=ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
    return "<a href='/sites/team/Lists/ListB/NewForm.aspx?Title="+title+"&ListAItemId=" + currentId + "' target='_blank'>Link ListB</a>";
}
```

2.Edit the list view page and edit the list web part. Go to Miscellaneous -> JS Link.

3.Add the following URL into the JS Link textbox.

**~site/SiteAssets/LinkField.js**

[image]

4.To get the data from "List A" in the "List B" newform.aspx page, we can use the JS function below, example, get Title from "List A". Add the code into Script Editor web part in the newform.aspx page.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //get Title value from list A
    var title=getUrlParameter("Title");
    //set title to Title field in list B
    $("input[title='Title Required Field']").val(title);
});
function getUrlParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\]');
    var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)');
    var results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your help, is there a way that i can populate all the filed values from "list A" to "list B" newform.aspx using the ID of the list item in "list A" when user clicks on the button in "list A". because i want the values from "list A" which are going to populate must be disabled/non-editable fileds in "list B" newform.aspx.

Comment: You can get the "List A" item in "List B" newform.aspx base on the ID of the list item in "List A" using jQuery Ajax and REST API. Or we can pass the value   through the Link URL, like ?Field1=Value1&Field2=Value2.

Comment: HI, Thanks again, one thing, is it possible to provide any syntax please. greatly appreciable.

Comment: Hi samy, I change the reply, check if it helps you.

Comment: Hi LZ-WX, Thank you for your response. Using REST API i'm able retrieve one column value from the "List A", but i couldn't bind the value in "List B" newform.aspx with the same column name. could you please help binding the retrieved values in "List B". any code would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Samy, I modify the step 4 in the reply, check the code again.

Comment: Hi LZ-WX,  Thank you, thank you so much for your help so far, and sorry for asking again i hope you don't mind, i have a date and time field in both "list A" and "list B" which i need to split the date and time and assign it to the field in "list B", because i need to calculate the date and time (column name is "End date") before the submission of the form which needs to see whether it is on-time submission or late submission of the form, and which should send a notification to the user on time and late submission notification using workflow. please help me achieve this.